# How Do I Auto Reconnect my Discord.js Bot

Tags: bots, discord.js

So I have been hosting a bot for a discord server for a while and recently my WiFi has been acting up. It would stop and then start maybe after a minute or two. Discord's system of detecting if your bot is connected is called "Heartbeats" and these send roughly every 35-40 seconds. It will wait for the heartbeat to be received on the other end and if it doesn't after about another 35-40 it will shut down. Is there any way I can make it reconnect as soon as it goes down so there are no issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try using something like `nodemon`, an npm package that will automatically restart node programs on certain conditions (usually when a file is updated in the directory). You can set the nodemon config file to restart every x amount of time if it errors in some way (disconnecting from network), which would solve your disconnection issue. [This part](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#delaying-restarting) of the nodemon documentation is where you can find how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PM2 to automatically restarts the bot if it exits.
http://pm2.keymetrics.io/

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd suggest you host your bot on some cloud provider. So, no problem with your home wi-fi.

However, the Discord.js client might still disconnect from time to time without trying to reconnect.

A workaround I'm using is to ping the bot (HTTP GET request in my case) every 30 minutes, destroy the client and login again. The drawback is a downtime of a few seconds, but that's totally fine for my use case.

Answer (score -2):

No need to. Your discord bot will reconnect automatically.

Comment: No, It shuts down. It stops. There is no "auto reconnect".

Comment: It literally just takes some time. There is no way to manually turn on a discord bot other than running the code.